# UIWebView loading property never changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, key-value-observing

I've got a UIWebView that's loading a simple request like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"derp.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
[webView loadRequest:theRequest];
```

I have another method that executes some JavaScript on the webView. This method may be called multiple times from different sources (including webViewDidFinishLoad and viewDidAppear). To protect against errors I have wrapped this in an if statement like so:

```
if (!self.webView.loading) {
     ... do stuff....
}
```

The problem is self.webView.loading is ALWAYS 0. I have even tried to set up an observer (tried a few different variations.... not 100% sure of the sytnax):

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"webView.loading" options:0 context:NULL];
```

But observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: never gets called.

Comment: Are you 1. sure that you are not always re-instantiating the web view? 2. aware that the `if()` isn't going to poll the property (since it's not a loop)?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. If the webView is loading, the javaScript execution will be triggered by the callback. If it's not loading the first time the method is called, then that means the callback won't be fired.

Comment: Seems you are trying to check for the web view is loading at the very next line alter you have called loadRequest: on webview instance,but asfaras i know the flag loading will be changed once you got the delegate callback webView:didStartLoading or webView:didFinishLoading only !
HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

Better to implement the UIWebViewDelegate methods...

Set the delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
[webView setDelegate:self];
```

You can use

`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {`
 //do things once loaded }`

To get a call back when the load has completed and it's much more reliable than messing with KVO.

Comment: I can't do that in this scenario. The webview relies on some objective-c variables that are injected via javascript execution. Those variables change after the content is fetched, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hmmm that'll be problematic as I've never been able to use the loading property successfully and relied on the delegates. Will think about it...

Answer (score 0):

by looking at [UIWebView doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

isLoading = YES If the receiver is still loading content; otherwise, NO.
Then, is it possible that at this point the loading of your web view is already finished ?

Comment: I littered the whole class with NSLog's trying to figure out when/where isLoading would be true, but it never was.

Comment: Then you should implement the delegate of UIWebView and set a BOOL property to YES when you enter in -webViewDidFinishLoad: and test this BOOL value instead of webView.isLoading

Comment: That's what I ended up doing... But I thought that was the whole point of the loading property on UIWebView?

Comment: But if you enter in your if condition, that should be okay ? what kind of error did you have then ?